# Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, fatal-error

I'm trying to install Magento on the `ipage` server. In database connection setup stage I'm getting the error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in
>   /hermes/bosoraweb129/b1598/ipg.xxx/xxx/private/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Resource.php
>   on line 133.

I don't know what this error is saying.

Please anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: This is due to a database connection issue. Make sure the mysql server is running

Comment: @Sukeshini I hope so, Of course it is running because it is in ipage server.

Comment: Have a look at the follow question/answers and see if you can find out some more information about your error.